Terminal Github fingerprint not the same as Github Public Fingerprint. Safe to proceed?
I have set up SSH key for github according to the github documentation and added it to the agent and my github account.
When I want to test it using ssh -T git@github.com I get "WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!".
Terminal also outputs a fingerprint for the ED25519 key sent by the remote host.
I read that I have to check if this fingerprint matches one of the ones published by github on https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/githubs-ssh-key-fingerprints.
Sadly the fingerprint does not match any on this page.
The terminal then tells me that I can Add the correct host key in ~/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Is it safe to proceed with this step to fix the issue? Or is there another way to fix it? I heard that when the fingerprints do not match, you need to proceed with caution.
Hope you guys can help me!

How long has it been since you last communicated with GitHub? https://github.blog/2023-03-23-we-updated-our-rsa-ssh-host-key/
